# rellenar optionsCollection Struts

Tags: java, arraylist, struts

Tengo una duda para rellenar un optionsCollection de Struts.

Tengo un Action donde recupero los datos y a través de la request le paso el resultado. A partir de aquí ponga lo que ponga en el option me da error. Gracias de antemano. Dejo código del Action de Struts.

```
    EquipoDAOInter equipoDao = new EquipoDAO();
    GenericDao generic = new GenericDao();
    List<Equipo> listadoEquipo = equipoDao.listaEquipos();
    request.setAttribute("listaEquipos", listadoEquipo);

    return mapping.getInputForward();
```

La clase la tengo asociada al Formulario, por un lado tengo la clase equipo y por otro el Form donde instancio la clase.

Pongo código del select:

```
<html:select property="equipo" value="Select">
  <html:option value="Select">Select</html:option>
  <html:optionsCollection name="equipoForm" property="equipo" label="" value="" /> 
</html:select>
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? ¿Al ejecutar qué código?

Comment: Hola! me lanza el siguiente error. Cannot create iterator for ...

Comment: pongo codigo del select.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                            
 <html:select property="equipo" value="Select">
           <html:option value="Select">Select</html:option>
           <html:optionsCollection name="equipoForm" 
                                 property="equipo" label="" value="" /> </html:select>

Comment: Dale al botón de "editar" para modificar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no has definido correctamente donde está la lista de equipos: el atributo name debería ser listaEquipos y no equipoForm

Comment: En un principio lo hice así, pero me da este error:                                                  No getter method for property: "equipo" of bean: "listaEquipos"